# Kivy android app kv-language not working properly

Tags: android, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I recently wrote an android app for the company I´m working at and started using the kv-lang for the layout. On Windows10 and Linux it´s running perfectly though when compiling it using buildozer and running it on android the whole layout is bugged and the size of the widget is way to large. I recompiled a couple of times and it still isn´t working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ6QI.jpg

Has someone encountered the same issue and if yes how did you fix it?

`my buildozer.spec`

https://pastebin.com/w8y2ibcs

Comment: The problem is likely to be in your code, not in your `spec` file.

Comment: But what could be in my code that makes the sizes work on Windows/Linux but not on android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using a relative font_size which compiled with the PC 16:9 format. Removed that part and it works.